# Foreign Characters not showing up correctly in php

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I am saving some foreign characters quite fine into my mysql database. This is the ones I am using right now for example: いち

When I try to echo out that column from the database, it only shows up as '??'

Why are there question marks showing up when I am trying to echo foreign characters?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you didn't set proper Mysql client's encoding.
You must issue a `SET NAMES <encoding>` query where `<encoding>` is your HTML page encoding.

Please note that there are no "foreign characters" but only **encoding**.
You have to know what encoding your characters in and set it up properly in all three web-application parts:

- Database. Table's encoding must be set to match actual data encoding.
- PHP as a database's client encoding. SET NAMES mentioned above.
- Browser's encoding. Set by header mentioned fellow SO'ers above or by other server setting.

Answer (score 0):

What encoding are you using in your database, and what encoding are you sending to the browser either via `header()` or HTML? Make sure they match the data you're putting in.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your database encoding as well as specify the encoding in the PHP headers to UTF-8. MySQL allows you to choose a default encoding, or on a per-table or per-field basis.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

If you keep the encoding of your database and that of your scripts consistent you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In order for those characters to be supported, you must choose

- a character set that contains those characters, typically [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)
- a character encoding that maps the characters to the underlying bytestream, typically, [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or, less frequently, [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Let's go with Unicode/UTF-8, because that's the recommended standard. You must ensure these things:

- The data you insert into the database is in UTF-8, or, if it isn't, you must convert it (e.g. with [iconv](http://www.php.net/iconv) or [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding)). If you are insert data from HTML forms, make sure you add the attribute `accept-charset="utf-8"` to your `<form>` elements.
- Your database must support unicode. In MySQL, see the [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-database.html) syntax and the [supported character sets/collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html) (read: encodings). You should pick UTF-8/Unicode.
- The database must know the PHP MySQL driver will be passed strings in UTF-8 (i.e., the client encoding must be set to UTF-8). In MySQL, this is done with executing the SQL statement `SET NAMES UTF8`.
- The web server must declare its content is encoded in UTF-8. In PHP, this is done with `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Fixed set names and accept-charset. BTW, feel free to fix it yourself.